# Encoder for multi label classfication

Tags: encoding, multilabel-classification

I am encoding for multi label classfication problem(5 labels).I use PolynomialWrapper(base encoder=TargetEncoder)  but when i fit_transform on same a feature  occur error is:Columns to be encoded can not contain new values.How to i fix this bug? Many thanks !

I tried to fit then transform instead of fit_transform but nothing changes.